# Lighting a model (cube,sphere....) in fragment shader cg/Unity

Tags: c, unity-game-engine, model, cg

I am  beginner at  modelling and etc., but I have  a school task  which I explained in the title and I searched for  tutorials and I found many at Unity's page, but I didn't find anything about lighting in fragment shader. Any lead how  to start?

Comment: For unity questions, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend checking out https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx
The samples are a great resource to get started.

If you feel you need to know more about computer graphics, how the pipeline works and some of the math. I would recommend taking this free course https://www.udacity.com/course/cs291